# How to truncate magento table using collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, collection

I have a custom table. I want to **truncate the table using Magento collection** without SQL query.

Hope someone will provide some useful information.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete some rows based on some condition?

Comment: No, I need to delete all records and also Auto Increment id  start with 1.

Answer (score 19):

Magento does not have a support for this (as far as I know).
But you can implement a method in your resource model (not the collection resource model) that will truncate the table.
Something like this:

```
public function truncate() {
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->getMainTable());
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can call it in your code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('[module]/[entity]')->truncate();
```

But this is a very dangerous approach. The `truncate` statement breaks the transaction, so it cannot be rolled back in case you need to.
I suggest deleteing every entity in the table instead.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[module]/[entity]')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

The down side of this is that it doesn't reset the increment id of the table. But it's safer.

**EDIT**.
To update the increment id of the main table you can add a new method in your resource model that does something like this.

```
public function changeAutoIncrement($increment = 1) {
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query('ALTER TABLE '.$this->getMainTable().' AUTO_INCREMENT = '. $increment);
}
```

Then call your method in the code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('[module]/[entity]')->changeAutoIncrement();
```

Comment: could you tell me three types of models in magento.thanks in advance

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. There is the entity model. Example: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. There is the resource model. Example: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`. And there is the collection resource model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`.

Comment: @Marius  Can you tell me How to update auto increment id ( its means start with 1 ) available in magento collection.

Comment: @VijayS. See my update to the answer.

Comment: @Marius i have one doubt. then what is Flat model and EAV model?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. Maybe you should ask a new question and explain what you need. Our discussion has no value to this question.

Comment: there is no truncate function for resource models: `$installer->getConnection()->truncate(Mage::getResourceModel('[module]/[entity]')->getMainTable())`

Answer (score 12):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('[module]/[model]');
$resource = $model->getResource();
$connection = $resource->getReadConnection();
/* @see Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */
$connection->truncateTable($resource->getMainTable());
$connection->changeTableAutoIncrement($resource->getMainTable(), 1);
```

***Note:*** MySQL resets autoincrement value to `1` when truncate a table, so it isn't required, but `changeTableAutoIncrement` may be useful if someone want to have AI starting with another value.

---

**Edit:**

This question was tagged with [magento-1.7](/questions/tagged/magento-1.7)/[magento-1.8](/questions/tagged/magento-1.8) ... just to complete the answer:

- `changeTableAutoIncrement` was added in 1.8.0.1
- `truncateTable` was added in 1.6.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 2):

> If if want to truncate the custom table in your controller, Cron, and Block so you can first use create the modal/collection on their constructor and use the below structure for the same, and also you can use code as per your requirement.: Below patterns is used in Magento 2.

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModelFactory;
.....
class Collect extends ....
{

protected $_modelFactory;
......

public function __construct(
   .....
   .....
    ModelFactory $modelFactory

) {
    .....
    $this->_modelFcatory = $modelFactory;
    
}
public function execute()
{
        $connection = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection()->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection()->getMainTable();
        $connection->truncateTable($tableName);
 }
}
```

> Hope This helps You.

Comment: Question was about M1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just added the answer has anyone searched the same issue in M2 so it will help it.
Thanks

Comment: Its only to get some reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

I have create a Model and for some development i had to implement delete method. It is very easy. I also try for conditional delete but i didn't get exact code. But i am using the following code which will fulfill your requirement for conditional delete.

```
$items = Mage::getModel('custom/csaabandonedcart')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('csa_id',Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
    ->getCustomerId())->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $retailer)
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $spid);

foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item->delete();
}
```

Comment: I am asking about truncate the table. Not to delete the record.

Comment: you can do using the following code. if you consider the above code reference.
 
$items->truncate();