# Truncate table using resource model in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, model, resource-model, delete

I have a custom module and i want to add remove every data including the increment id, using resource model in magento 2, i've read the solution in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16056/how-to-truncate-magento-table-using-collection) but this is for magento 1, i'm not sure how to do it in magento 2, for example like this:

```
$model->getCollection()->truncate();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can truncate table using DB Adapter and table name.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection */
$connection = $model->getResource()->getConnection();
$tableName = $model->getResource()->getMainTable();
$connection->truncateTable($tableName);
```

Alternatively you can get DB Adapter and table name from collection, but resource model rather.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection */
$connection = $model->getCollection()->getConnection();
$tableName = $model->getCollection()->getMainTable();
$connection->truncateTable($tableName);
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Create a function in your ResourceModel**

**app\code\Module\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel**

**Inventory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Module\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel;

class Inventory extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
     protected function _construct()
     {
          $this->_init('your table name', 'primary key column name');
     }
    public function truncateTable()
        {
            if ($this->getConnection()->getTransactionLevel() > 0) {
                $this->getConnection()->delete($this->getMainTable());
            } else {
                $this->getConnection()->truncateTable($this->getMainTable());
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
}
```

> And call this function from any file in your custom module.
> This must delete the table related to the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 can't provide directly to truncate resource collection.

Use Install/Upgrade Data script by using setup command

**DB Adapter** : Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::truncateTable($tableName, $schemaName)

> app/code/[vender_name]/[module_name]/setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace <vender>\<module>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Category attribute Upgrade Data script
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        // truncate table
        $connection->truncateTable($tableName);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure? what about dynamic index tables, flat tables, report tables?  Are we need to trancate tables only using setup? I doubt it. We can use collection object as way to retrieve adapter for table and tablename for execute trancation but you can use other way to fetch this objects.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich getConnection() is DB adapter method, so no need to load collection for truncate any table. it's will use directly

Answer (score 1):

> If if want to truncate the custom table in your controller, Cron, and Block so you can first use create the modal/collection on their constructor and use the below structure for the same, and also you can use code as per your requirement.

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModelFactory;
.....
class Collect extends ....
{

protected $_modelFactory;
......

public function __construct(
   .....
   .....
    ModelFactory $modelFactory

) {
    .....
    $this->_modelFcatory = $modelFactory;
    
}
public function execute()
{
        $connection = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection()->getConnection();
        $tableName = $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection()->getMainTable();
        $connection->truncateTable($tableName);
 }
}
```

> Hope This helps You.