# Magento 2 split order based on product attribute

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, quote, multi-vendor

I'm developing a Multivendor marketplace module. I need to split orders based on seller id's which assigned to the product. I tried using this free module. [Link](https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order) But this is not working with attributes. So I tried to split with SKU. Where I modified the code as below.

```
<?php

namespace Magestat\SplitOrder\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magestat\SplitOrder\Api\QuoteHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Class SplitQuote
 * Interceptor to \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement
 */
class SplitQuote
{
    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var QuoteFactory
     */
    private $quoteFactory;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var QuoteHandlerInterface
     */
    private $quoteHandler;

    /**
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param QuoteHandlerInterface $quoteHandler
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        QuoteHandlerInterface $quoteHandler
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->quoteHandler = $quoteHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Places an order for a specified cart.
     *
     * @param QuoteManagement $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param int $cartId
     * @param string $payment
     * @return mixed
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @see \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface
     */
    public function aroundPlaceOrder(QuoteManagement $subject, callable $proceed, $cartId, $payment = null)
    {
        $currentQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

        // Separate all items in quote into new quotes.
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quotes = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $quotes[$item->getProduct()->getSku()][] = $item;
        } //Here where I modified to split with skus

        // Collect list of data addresses.
        $addresses = $this->quoteHandler->collectAddressesData($currentQuote);

        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface[] $orders */
        $orders = [];
        $orderIds = [];
        foreach ($quotes as $items) {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $split */
            $split = $this->quoteFactory->create();

            // Set all customer definition data.
            $this->quoteHandler->setCustomerData($currentQuote, $split);
            $this->toSaveQuote($split);

            // Map quote items.
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // Add item by item.
                $item->setId(null);
                $split->addItem($item);
            }
            $this->quoteHandler->populateQuote($quotes, $split, $items, $addresses, $payment);

            // Dispatch event as Magento standard once per each quote split.
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_submit_before',
                ['quote' => $split]
            );

            $this->toSaveQuote($split);
            $order = $subject->submit($split);

            $orders[] = $order;
            $orderIds[$order->getId()] = $order->getIncrementId();

            if (null == $order) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Please try to place the order again.'));
            }
        }
        $currentQuote->setIsActive(false);
        $this->toSaveQuote($currentQuote);

        $this->quoteHandler->defineSessions($split, $order, $orderIds);

        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_submit_all_after',
            ['orders' => $orders, 'quote' => $currentQuote]
        );
        return $this->getOrderKeys($orderIds);
    }

    /**
     * Save quote
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return \Magestat\SplitOrder\Plugin\SplitQuote
     */
    private function toSaveQuote($quote)
    {
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $orderIds
     * @return array
     */
    private function getOrderKeys($orderIds)
    {
        $orderValues = [];
        foreach (array_keys($orderIds) as $orderKey) {
            $orderValues[] = (string) $orderKey;
        }
        return array_values($orderValues);
    }    
}
```

but it returns the below error in the console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

/master/bike/rest/bike/V1/carts/mine/payment-information:1 
<message>
The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.
</message>
```

It shows that customer is not authenticated. The rest api throws error in onepage. I need a experts help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources. Mean you dont have permission with the api consumer, check this first

Comment: All permission is enabled in admin. the issue is with above code

Comment: I think you may need to do some customization for Orders. Same as multi-shipping module done in core Magento. You might need to create a module same like that multi-shipping. not sure.

Comment: can you explain how the payment process is happening with your order? would be good to understand if the payment is taken

Comment: I've done order splitting in multiple projects. The best way to split orders is after the checkout. I split quote items using QuoteManagement plugin `aroundSubmit`. Then split orders based on these quote items after the checkout using `checkout_submit_all_after` event. Also one more important point, just splitting the quote will not work. You will have to create new orders using order entity object.

Comment: Could you please help me how to use aroundSubmit plugin

Comment: Sure. I can provide the overview of both plugin and observer. You can do changes as per your requirement.

Comment: in your requirement, can one product have multiple vendors?? if yes then only you will require quotemanagement plugin.

Comment: No for now I don't have such requirement. Only one vendor for one product

Answer (score 1):

In the CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver, I split orders based on order(quote) items.

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if (!$order) {
        return $this;
    }
    $orders = $this->splitOrders($order);
 }

public function splitOrders($order)
{
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    //rearrange my items based on vendor. so order is split vendor wise.
    $list = [
        'vendor1' => [orderItem 1, orderItem 2],
        'vendor2' => [orderItem 3, orderItem 4],
    ]
    $c = 1;
    $baseShippingAmnt = $order->getBaseShippingAmount();
    if ($baseShippingAmnt) {
        $baseShippingAmnt = round($order->getBaseShippingAmount() / count($list), 4);
    }
    foreach ($list as $vid => $orderItems) {
        if ($c > 1) {
            $newOrder = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $newOrder->setData($this->getRequiredDataOfOrder($order->getData()));
            $payment = $order->getPayment();
            $payment->setId(null);
            $payment->setParentId(null);
            $newOrder->setPayment($payment);

            $addresses = $order->getAddresses();
            foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                $address->setId(null);
                $address->setParentId(null);
                $newOrder->addAddress($address);
            }

            /** Save state and status value for next save to leave order pending */
            $state = $newOrder->getState();
            $status = $newOrder->getStatus();
            $this->orderRepository->save($newOrder);

            foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
                if ($orderItem->getParentItemId()) {
                    $parentOrderItem = $this->orderItemRepository->get($orderItem->getParentItemId());
                    $parentOrderItem->setOrderId($newOrder->getId());
                    $this->orderItemRepository->save($parentOrderItem);
                }
                $orderItem->setOrderId($newOrder->getId());
                $this->orderItemRepository->save($orderItem);
            }
            /** Change state from complete */
            if ($newOrder->getState() != $state || $newOrder->getStatus() != $status) {
                $newOrder->setState($state);
                $newOrder->setStatus($status);
                $this->orderRepository->save($newOrder);
            }

            $order = $this->setRequiredDataOfOrder(
                $orderItems,
                $newOrder,
                $this->setShippingNewAmnt($newOrder, $vid, $baseShippingAmnt)
            );
            $orders[] = $order;
        } else {
            $order = $this->setRequiredDataOfOrder(
                $orderItems,
                $order,
                $this->setShippingNewAmnt($order, $vid, $baseShippingAmnt)
            );
            $orders[] = $order;
        }
        $c++;
    }

    return $orders;
}

private function setShippingNewAmnt($order, $vid, $amount)
{
    //set shipping amount as per your requirements
    $method = $order->getShippingMethod(true);
    return $amount;
}

private function getRequiredDataOfOrder($data)
{
    $unsetKeys = ['entity_id', 'parent_id', 'item_id', 'order_id'];
    foreach ($unsetKeys as $key) {
        if (isset($data[$key])) {
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    $unsetKeys = ['increment_id', 'items', 'addresses', 'payment'];
    foreach ($unsetKeys as $key) {
        if (isset($data[$key])) {
            $data[$key] = null;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}

private function setRequiredDataOfOrder($orderItems, $order, $baseShippingAmnt)
{
    $totalQty = 0;
    $subTotal = 0;
    $baseSubTotal = 0;
    $subTotalInclTax = 0;
    $baseSubTotalInclTax = 0;
    $discount = 0;
    $baseDiscount = 0;
    $tax = 0;
    $baseTax = 0;

    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        if ($orderItem->getParentItemId()) {
            $parentOrderItem = $this->orderItemRepository->get($orderItem->getParentItemId());
            $totalQty += $parentOrderItem->getQtyOrdered();
            $subTotal += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                $parentOrderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $parentOrderItem->getPrice()
            );
            $baseSubTotal += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                $parentOrderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $parentOrderItem->getBasePrice()
            );
            $subTotalInclTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                $parentOrderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $parentOrderItem->getPriceInclTax()
            );
            $baseSubTotalInclTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                $parentOrderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $parentOrderItem->getBasePriceInclTax()
            );
            if ($parentOrderItem->getDiscountPercent()) {
                $discount += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $subTotal * ($parentOrderItem->getDiscountPercent() / 100)
                );
                $baseDiscount += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $baseSubTotal * ($parentOrderItem->getDiscountPercent() / 100)
                );
            }
            if ($parentOrderItem->getTaxPercent()) {
                $tax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $subTotal * ($parentOrderItem->getTaxPercent() / 100)
                );
                $baseTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $baseSubTotal * ($parentOrderItem->getTaxPercent() / 100)
                );
            }
        } else {
            if ($orderItem->getPrice() > 0) {
                $totalQty += $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
                $subTotal += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $orderItem->getPrice()
                );
                $baseSubTotal += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $orderItem->getBasePrice()
                );
                $subTotalInclTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $orderItem->getPriceInclTax()
                );
                $baseSubTotalInclTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                    $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() * $orderItem->getBasePriceInclTax()
                );
                if ($orderItem->getDiscountPercent()) {
                    $discount += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                        $subTotal * ($orderItem->getDiscountPercent() / 100)
                    );
                    $baseDiscount += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                        $baseSubTotal * ($orderItem->getDiscountPercent() / 100)
                    );
                }
                if ($orderItem->getTaxPercent()) {
                    $tax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                        $subTotal * ($orderItem->getTaxPercent() / 100)
                    );
                    $baseTax += $this->priceCurrency->round(
                        $baseSubTotal * ($orderItem->getTaxPercent() / 100)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $amountDiscount = $discount;
    $baseAmountDiscount = $baseDiscount;
    if ($discount > 0) {
        $amountDiscount = -$discount;
        $baseAmountDiscount = -$baseDiscount;
    }
    $shippingAmount = $this->priceCurrency->convert($this->priceCurrency->round($baseShippingAmnt));

    $order->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseAmountDiscount);
    $order->setDiscountAmount($amountDiscount);
    $order->setBaseTaxAmount($baseTax);
    $order->setTaxAmount($tax);
    $order->setBaseGrandTotal($baseSubTotal - $baseDiscount + $baseTax + $baseShippingAmnt);
    $order->setGrandTotal($subTotal - $discount + $tax + $shippingAmount);
    $order->setBaseSubtotal($baseSubTotal);
    $order->setSubtotal($subTotal);
    $order->setTotalQtyOrdered($totalQty);
    $order->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($baseSubTotalInclTax);
    $order->setSubtotalInclTax($subTotalInclTax);
    $order->setBaseTotalDue($baseSubTotal - $baseDiscount);
    $order->setTotalDue($subTotal - $discount);
    $order->setBaseShippingAmount($baseShippingAmnt);
    $order->setBaseShippingInclTax($baseShippingAmnt);
    $order->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
    $order->setShippingInclTax($shippingAmount);
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);

    return $order;
}
```

The QuoteManagement Plugin I've separated the quote items based on different vendors. Note- This is only required if one product can be associated to multiple vendors. In my case the vendor was decided by priority.

```
public function aroundSubmit(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    $orderData = []
) {
    /*@var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
    $this->cart->setQuote($quote);
    $this->separateItemsVendorBasis();
    $this->save();

    return $proceed($quote, $orderData);
}

//separate items based on your requirement, like vendor wise product
private function separateItemsVendorBasis()
{
    $count = [];
    foreach ($this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
        $itemId = $quoteItem->getId();
        //i get all vendors for that product
        $allVItems = $this->getVendorsProduct($quoteItem->getProduct()->getId());
        if( !isset($count[$itemId]) )
            $count[$itemId] = 1;

        foreach ($allVItems as $item) {
            if ($count[$itemId] == 1) {
                //for existing quote item
                $quoteItem->setVendorId($item->getVendorId());
                if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                    $quoteItem->getParentItem()->setQty($item->getQty());
                    $quoteItem->getParentItem()->setVendorId($item->getVendorId());
                } else {
                    $quoteItem->setQty($item->getQty());
                }
            } else {
                //creating new quote item
                $info = $quoteItem->getBuyRequest();
                $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
                if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                    $product = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct();
                    $info = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getBuyRequest();
                }
                $info->setQty($item->getQty());
                $info->setOriginalQty($item->getQty());
                $info->unsetData('uenc');
                $newQuoteItem = $this->cart->addProduct($product, $info);
                $newQuoteItem->setProduct($product);
                $newQuoteItem->setVendorId($item->getVendorId());
                $newQuoteItem->save();
                if ($newQuoteItem->getHasChildren()) {
                    foreach ($newQuoteItem->getChildren() as $newQuoteChildrens) {
                        $newQuoteChildrens->setVendorId($item->getVendorId());
                        $newQuoteChildrens->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have to create a observer? CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver
Can you please mention the event

Comment: Yes. this observer is called after the order is placed.

Comment: checkout_submit_all_after this event right?

Comment: yes. "checkout_submit_all_after"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code in the question splits the answer but the authorisation error occurs. Have any idea on it?

Comment: Authorisation error is occurring because the payment api is getting hit. After an order has been placed, this api should not get hit at all. You'll have to check, after which action this api is getting hit or if this function `getPaymentInformation` is getting called directly so as to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the below code change and try if it helps!

```
public function aroundPlaceOrder(QuoteManagement $subject, callable $proceed, $cartId, $payment = null)
    { 

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $paymentMethod = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->getData();
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();

        ......
        ......

        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {

            // Split Quote
            $split = $this->quoteFactory->create();
            $split->setCustomer($quote->getCustomer());

            // Save split to get a quote id for each item
            $this->quoteRepository->save($split);

            // Add item
            $item->setId(null);
            $split->addItem($item);

            // Set addresses
            $split->getBillingAddress()->setData($billingAddress);
            $split->getShippingAddress()->setData($shippingAddress);

            // Set payment menthod
            $split->getPayment()->setMethod($paymentMethod);

            ......
            ......

        }

    }
```

**OR**

Please set the `Allow Anonymous Guest Access` setting to "Yes and check if it works!
Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security.

More, check for user role and authentication token. Or maybe the session (auth token) expires. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Also, it could be an issue with the PHP version as well. Please visit the post [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/REST-API-The-consumer-isn-t-authorized-to-access-resources-2-3-1/td-p/133545).

Comment: This is not a valid answer. Please check my code and question not just the error.

Comment: @RameshKR I have updated the answer, please check if it helps!

Comment: hi, this also didn't worked

Comment: Please check this old post if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196669/magento-2-split-order-for-every-item

Comment: Thanks, I also tired this but same issue

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer above?

Comment: The code should work to split the quote per item.

Comment: it is spiting but 500 error in console log. [2020-06-04 08:33:05] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 2 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with customerId = 2 at /var/www/html/master/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} [] in exception log

Comment: Please check this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245953/no-such-entity-with-customerid/295470#295470 and https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411#issuecomment-556987380