# User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6, ddl

I want to achieve following functionality:

Whenever user tries to insert new data, i want to remove all old data from my custom table and insert new data.

For this, i want to use **truncateTable()** method. i am using code from below link:

[Truncate table using resource model in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155922/truncate-table-using-resource-model-in-magento-2)

But i am getting below error when i run code:

> Something went wrong while saving this configuration: User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transaction

Is there anyway we can truncate table using code?

**Note:** It works with **delete** but reason to use **truncate** is to reset my custom table's auto-increment key.

Comment: Hello Khushbu. you can try with database level programming.

Comment: You can create a database trigger for insert event for a particular table and try to delete the data and fill with a new value. There is also before and after the event too

Comment: Add me in skype if you want to explore it further skype: samumaretiya

Comment: ok i got your point. I will try this

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, I want to truncate table and Trigger creation gives error:  Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: As a solution of this error, i referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626215/truncate-table-with-a-trigger but it give syntax error near ````declare PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;````

Comment: I post the answer, magento provide the way to remove all the data from table using collection. you can use that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now i ended up with **delete** instead of **truncate**. Actually this is not the best solution because i want to reset my auto increment key in addition to deleting all data from my table. Still someone can use this code so i am sharing here:

> Solution with **delete** instead of **truncate** is as below:

```
<?php
class custom
{
    protected $connection;
    protected $dbresource;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $dbresource)
    {
        $this->connection = $dbresource->getConnection();
        $this->dbresource = $dbresource; 
    }

    public function mycustomfunction()
    {
        $table = $this->dbresource->getTableName("my_custom_table");
        $this->connection->delete(
                $table,
                ['1 = 1']
        );
    }
}
?>
```

I am still looking for a way to use **truncate**!!

Comment: Do you find any way to truncate table ?

Comment: @Kozame  No.. I used above solution only.

Answer (score 1):

To remove old data from database, you can use magento code as well.

```
<?php
use Vendor\Extension\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionFactory;

class Yourclass
{
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(.....
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    .....)
    {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       // To remove all old data.

       $mycollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                     ->getCollection();
       foreach ($mycollection as $myitem) {
            $myitem->delete();
        }

        // Now you can do code here to add new data
    }

}
```

Comment: I used delete code only and it's working right now. I will post that here too. but i was looking to use truncate because deleting won't reset my auto increment key. I hope you understand

Comment: Truncate means you need to remove all the data from table. And above code do the same things.

Comment: No truncate is different in many ways from delete. you can read this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65fc13/difference-between-delete-truncate-and-drop-statements-of-m/