# Create php script to truncate table

Tags: magento-1.9, script

I want to trunacate the table 'core_session' by loaded a php script.

How can I fix this, how should this script look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to load fancy pantsy models and stuff. It can be done much simpler. The only thing you need is a connection to the database:

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$connection->truncateTable('core_session');
```

or:

```
$connection->query('TRUNCATE TABLE `core_session`');
```

Having such scripts globally accessible in the root of your site is a huge security risk by the way, but we'll save that discussion for later.

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: Truncating table logic is taken from [@sv3n's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142184/3535)

Create a file `truncate.php` and put it in the root folder. Add below code in that PHP file:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();

$model      = Mage::getModel('core/session');
$resource   = $model->getResource();
$connection = $resource->getReadConnection();
/* @see Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */
$connection->truncateTable($resource->getMainTable());
$connection->changeTableAutoIncrement($resource->getMainTable(), 1);
echo "table is successfully truncated.";
```

Make sure you replace the `$model`  with your model. Now load the page `www.yourdomain.com/truncate.php`. You are done.

Also please consider going through [**Marius's answer**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16059/3535).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What exactly should I change in the `$model`, when I want to truncate table 'core_session'?

Comment: By the way, truncating a table in MySQL will by default reset the auto_increment value to 1 so you don't need to de that manually.

Comment: @GielBerkers I am 100% agreeing with you. [to OP]: I updated my answer with right model value. also keeping this script in the root folder is a big risk. [to Giel] : What your code does exactly same as what this code does. Instead of giving table name directly, we are just grabbing that from the model. This is the "Magento way". Even if table name changed in future (which is not going to happen, I know), this code will work.

Comment: Please try Giel's answer which is simpler than this.

Comment: Please don't put it in the root folder of your website, it is a huge security risk.